Find the amount of reward the node operator/validator received for including the block in that slot (in GWEI)
I've a GET /blockreward/{slot} API requirement where I need to retrieve information about the block reward for a given slot (integer) in the Ethereum blockchain.
JSON Response:
status: Whether the slot contains a block produced by a MEV relay or a vanilla block (built internally in the validator node).
reward: The amount of reward the node operator/validator received for including the block in that slot (in GWEI).
Error Handling:
Return HTTP 404 if the slot does not exist / was missed.
Return HTTP 400 if the requested slot is in the future.
Return HTTP 500 for any internal server errors.
How can I find this information ?
